# How to stop(or something like that) a function with another function?

Tags: function, pycharm

Ok so... I'm a newbie in pycharm and I have a question. The title is the question. How to stop(or something like that) a function with another function? I will show the code, but if there is a mistake that doesnt access the thing work, fix it if you want. And fix it so it works the same. And if its impossible then my game is dead. Hope I'm getting help! 'p.s I'm russian so the code has some of the russian text, I hope it doesn't prevent you.'
the "if player_gold < 1:" function should stop "if ya == '1':" function.

```
ya = input("0 - купить 2 силы за 1 золото. 1 - купить 2 ловкости за 1 золото. Торговец говорит больше атрибутов нету :(.")
if ya == '1':
    if player_gold < 1:
      time.sleep(2)
      print("У вас нету больше золота...")
      time.sleep(2)
      print("Вы пошли дальше в приключения!")
    player_gold = player_gold - 1
    stats[1] = stats[1] + 2
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Вы купили 2 ловкости! Ваша ловкость =",stats[1],"! Осталось золота =",player_gold,".")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Вы пошли дальше в приключения!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the built-in  [break](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue) function. This function will take you to the next scope you are currently inside. Here is an example:

```
break_=False

def break_test(break_):
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        if i==7:
            break_=True
        else:
            break_=False
        if break_==True:
            break         #This is the actually break function
    print("still inside break_test()")
```

Here is the output.

```
break_test(break_)

Out: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
still inside break test
```

You can see that what happens is when the for loop gets to 7 my variable `break_=True`. This causes the if statement `if break_==True:` to evaluate as True, so the built-in python function `break` is called. However, this does not completely stop the code from running. This breaks the current for loop, but you can see that the print statement that is inside `break_test()` still prints.

Comment: i kinda didnt understand how does it work... may you use it on my code? so it would be a better example for me i guess? because my game is not made by experts :L i cant understand some things like your example so im asking for an example that has my code

Comment: Hi! Please comment your code to show where the break function should go, then I will make my answer with your code.